# What is an adjective or phrase to qualify a small number of something but that is important?

Tags: adjectives, synonyms

I'm trying to find an adjective or a periphrasis to qualify a substance that can be found in small quantities but that is here whatever, and has a important effect on the system where it can be found.

For example, the use of "a drop of vanilla" in a recipe while most of the cake is made of flavour, sugar, etc. is a good context. My context is more about the presence of a few catalyst molecules in a mix, to say that we found them in very low quantity but their presence in this small quantity changes a lot, despite their low numbers.

In French, we use "*substantiel*" (small in quantity but important effect), which translates mostly into "substantial" but not for this specific use, and which seems inappropriate for this use.

Comment: Not sure if **necessary** would do the job for you. (Of course, nothing of the sort *found in small quantities* is explicit in the meaning itself!)

Comment: I use *key* to assign outsized importance to the undersized.

Comment: 'Vanilla essence' is virtually a compound noun, and 'essence' carries the << 4a (1): a constituent or derivative possessing the special qualities (as of a plant or drug) in concentrated form >> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/essence) sense while 'of the essence' (of the utmost importance) and 'essential' carry the 'vitally needed' sense. But not ideal (and not always applicable).

Comment: What does it mean to be "here whatever"? I can't get past the definition. As noted, sentences are useful instead of attempts at descriptions.

Comment: Can other French speakers confirm that the sense of "small in quantity" is baked in to *substantiel*? And how does it compare to *essentiel*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would help if you gave a sentence where you would use the word. Without context I am not very sure, but maybe ***subtle*** can work:

> *Subtle* can ... mean ***small but important***:
>
> - There are ***subtle*** differences between the two. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/subtle))

You could say that this substance has a *subtle influence*.

Rather than finding an adjective describing the substance, it might be easier to describe its effect. You could also say that

> This substance has an *[appreciable](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/appreciable)* effect on the system.

Comment: I propose that the use of "a drop of vanilla" in a recipe while most of the cake is made of flavour, sugar, etc. is a good context. My context is more about the present of a few catalyst molecules in a mix, to say that we found them in very low quantity but their presences at this small quantity change a lot, despite their low numbers. hope it helps? :S

Comment: You could play with 2 adjectives then: _**trivial but influential/essential/indispensable** quantity_, or something along those lines. I doubt you will find only one adjective.

Comment: I'm surprised at the 'small _but important_' sense Cambridge licenses (though others have 'insidious [eg a subtle poison]' which is of course important). I can't find it in any of the other free online dictionaries.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I guess it depends on the noun it modifies. I agree that when it describes effect or influence or impact, Cambridge is right.

Answer (score 4):

The fixed phrase **seemingly insignificant** is listed by [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/seemingly-insignificant), though they define each word individually:

> **insignificant** [adjective]
>
> Something that is insignificant is unimportant, especially because it
> is very small
>
> **seemingly** [adverb; {modifier of adjective here}]
>
> If something is seemingly the case, you mean that it appears to be the
> case, even
> though it may not really be so. [...]

So with the 'vanilla' example,

- One needs the merest drop of vanilla flavoring in this recipe, a seemingly insignificant amount.

Note also that in 'a mere / the merest drop / pinch', *mere* and *merest* themselves carries the sense 'extremely' with a hint of 'surprisingly'.

Comment: it sounds to express this paradox (even in the use of these two words). Thanks

Comment: I accepted the proposal from "fev" as subtle in Cambridge has this precise definition; But i think your proposal does the job by even expressing explicitly the paradox. I would have to possibility to accept your proposal also. Thank a lot Edwin!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't think there is a common fixed expression for this idea in English. I would spell it out with a phrase like "small in quantity but significant in effect."